# Как узнать, прокручена ли до конца полоса прокрутки?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Нужно узнать, до конца ли прокручен блок. Понятия не имею, как это можно сделать.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`elem.scrollHeight` — высота всего содержимого, в том числе и за пределами скролла,

`elem.scrollTop` — сколько уже прокрутили,

`elem.clientHeight` — внутренняя высота блока, с учетом padding, без учета рамок.

```js
document.querySelector(".bubu").addEventListener("scroll", function() {
  console.clear();
  
  console.log(
    "↓↑ end:", this.scrollHeight === this.scrollTop + this.clientHeight,

    this.scrollHeight, this.scrollTop, this.clientHeight
  );
    
  console.log(
    "←→ end:", this.scrollWidth === this.scrollLeft + this.clientWidth,

    this.scrollWidth, this.scrollLeft, this.clientWidth
  );
});
```

```css
.bubu {
  width: 200px;
  height: 140px;
  overflow: auto;
}

.content {
  width: 400px;
  height: 900px;
  background-image:
    repeating-linear-gradient(to right, #a22 0 20px, transparent 20px 40px),
    repeating-linear-gradient(#a22 0 20px, #fea 20px 40px);
}
```

```html
<div class="bubu">
  <div class="content"></div>
</div>
```